# Locale not recognised Error while creating Datasource (connecting with oracle db)

Tags: jboss, locale, rhel7, ojdbc, appserver

I am using Jboss as app server (RHEL-7). I have to create datasource to connect with oracle (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0) db.

To create DS, using ojdbc driver. When I try to do test connection, in logs I am getting "Locale not recognised" error. To be specific getting below error in logs:

`converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/user.country] not found - trying original name [user.country]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/user.country -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.iconnect-worklist.iconnect-worklist.env."user.country"`

when I run locale command :

`locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory LANG==en_IN.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_TIME="=en_IN.UTF-8"LC_COLLATE="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_MESSAGES="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_PAPER="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_NAME="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_ADDRESS="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_TELEPHONE="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_MEASUREMENT="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_IDENTIFICATION="=en_IN.UTF-8" LC_ALL=`

when I run java -XshowSettings command:

```
`sun.os.patch.level = unknown
user.country = US
user.dir = /home/appadmin
user.home = /home/appadmin
user.language = en
user.name = appadmin
user.timezone =
Locale settings:
default locale = English
default display locale = English (United States)
default format locale = English (United States)`
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: What does "locale -a" output?

Comment: output: it lists down all the possible locale we can set..
locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
aa_DJ
aa_DJ.iso88591
aa_DJ.utf8
aa_ER
aa_ER.utf8
aa_ER.utf8@saaho
.....

Comment: Locales are clearly garbled. I suggest you tag with "locale" "rhel" and remove the Java related stuff. At which point it's more a linux sysad question than programming per se. And so better moved onto  linux&unix stackexchange where you're more likely to find ppl expert in this. (Not me!  Not used rhel in decades)

Comment: Thank you Rusi for your help. I have updated tags as suggested by you..